# Why is the 2-argument overload of Enumerable.Zip() in .NET Core but not in .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I create a new project in my Visual Studio of type class library, .NET Core, C# and paste in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Method()
        {
            var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            var chars = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

            foreach (var (n, c) in Enumerable.Zip(numbers, chars))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{n}, {c}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler accepts this without complaining.

Now I create a new project of type class library, .NET Standard, C# and I paste in the same code and change the namespace. The compiler now gives these errors:

```
1>[path]\Class1.cs(15,47,15,50): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'resultSelector' of 'Enumerable.Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>)'
1>[path]\Class1.cs(15,36,15,66): error CS1061: 'TResult' does not contain a definition for 'Deconstruct' and no accessible extension method 'Deconstruct' accepting a first argument of type 'TResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>[path]\Class1.cs(15,36,15,66): error CS8129: No suitable 'Deconstruct' instance or extension method was found for type 'TResult', with 2 out parameters and a void return type.
1>[path]\Class1.cs(15,27,15,28): error CS8130: Cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable 'n'.
1>[path]\Class1.cs(15,30,15,31): error CS8130: Cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable 'c'.
```

If I invoke "go to definition" on Enumerable.Zip in each copy of the code, I see that in the Enumerable accessible to the .NET Core project there are two overloads of Zip() but in the Enumerable accessible to the .NET Standard project there is only one. The 2-argument overload is missing. A small number of other methods are also missing from the .NET Standard version: SkipLast(), TakeLast() and ToHashSet(). Why are these methods and in particular, the overload of Zip() omitted from .NET Standard?

Comment: Maybe they exist in some github project.

Comment: This question is, I'm afraid, off topic because most people (and by this I mean very nearly everyone) here are unable to *objectively* answer questions of the ilk "what was the relevant team at Microsoft thinking when..." unless by chance it catches the attention of someone from the relevant dev team (not unheard of but it doesn't make this kind of question generally on topic). As such it's essentially canvassing for opinions on why there is a difference between std and core

Comment: It seems to me that if there is no objective reason why it's missing, then you could answer to that effect and that that would be an answer. Sometimes the answer to a question of the form "why is x the way it is" is "there is no reason"; that doesn't mean there was a fault with the question, and the fact that the way of things is arbitrary is information of a kind. I dispute that the question is "canvassing for opinions on why there is a difference"; in order for me to be doing that I would have had to be aware in the first place that the difference is arbitrary, which I wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Standard is a common library that is supported by both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

`Enumerable.Zip` only has one overload in .NET Framework, and in fact, the second overload was only introduced in .NET Core 3.0.

.NET Framework isn't actively being updated by Microsoft any more, hence the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like this to work in a class library, .NET Standard, C#, the following code is what you would be looking for. You will need to define the result selector "`Func<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>` A function that specifies how to merge the elements from the two sequences."

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var chars = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

foreach (var (n,c) in Enumerable.Zip(numbers, chars, (n, c) => (n, c)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{n}, {c}");
}
```